# php and javascript player base64_encode?

Tags: javascript, php

So I have a player that plays a video but shows the video url in page source which I would like to obscure with base64_encode.

One player works with base64_encode and gets the item url with the following php code

```
                    $filenew = substr($video->filename,$startIndex+1);
                $videofilepath = base64_encode($filenew);
                $object = "<video id='single_player_".$unique_id."'>".JText::_('LOADING_PLAYER')."</video>

                            <script type='text/javascript' defer='defer'> 
                                jwplayer('single_player_".$unique_id."').setup({
                                    flashplayer: '".$player."', 
                                    file: '".$videofilepath."',
```

Then in another file the base64_encode url is decoded and plays the video fine.

However in the same file as above code there is a player that calls the url using javascript. The code is as follows

```
                                    events: { onReady: function() { 

                                                          var newItem=Array();
                                                          for(var j=0;j<fileTotal;j++)
                                                           {

                                                            newItem[j]={file:videos_position_url[j].substr(startIndex+1);

                                                           }
                                                        jwplayer().load(newItem);
```

How would one go about encoding the 'videos_position_url' in base64? Also so it is decoded possibly with same code as in the other file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If encoding is proper, you might not get any errors in decoding the string.
I assume you are looking for decoding any string (Video URL) which is encoded in base -64.
You can try, the below piece of code

```
/**
*
*  Base64 encode / decode
*  http://www.webtoolkit.info/
*
**/
var Base64 = {

// private property
_keyStr : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",

// public method for encoding
encode : function (input) {
    var output = "";
    var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;

    input = Base64._utf8_encode(input);

    while (i < input.length) {

        chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

        enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
        enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
        enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
        enc4 = chr3 & 63;

        if (isNaN(chr2)) {
            enc3 = enc4 = 64;
        } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
            enc4 = 64;
        }

        output = output +
        this._keyStr.charAt(enc1) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
        this._keyStr.charAt(enc3) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc4);

    }

    return output;
},

// public method for decoding
decode : function (input) {
    var output = "";
    var chr1, chr2, chr3;
    var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;

    input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

    while (i < input.length) {

        enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

        chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
        chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
        chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

        output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

        if (enc3 != 64) {
            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
        }
        if (enc4 != 64) {
            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
        }

    }

    output = Base64._utf8_decode(output);

    return output;

},

// private method for UTF-8 encoding
_utf8_encode : function (string) {
    string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
    var utftext = "";

    for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

        var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

        if (c < 128) {
            utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
        }
        else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
        }
        else {
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
        }

    }

    return utftext;
},

// private method for UTF-8 decoding
_utf8_decode : function (utftext) {
    var string = "";
    var i = 0;
    var c = c1 = c2 = 0;

    while ( i < utftext.length ) {

        c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);

        if (c < 128) {
            string += String.fromCharCode(c);
            i++;
        }
        else if((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
            c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
            string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
            i += 2;
        }
        else {
            c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
            c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+2);
            string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
            i += 3;
        }

    }

    return string;
}

}
```

Hope this solves your problem